# CORS header for API with a lot of clients

Tags: cors

I've read quite a lot about CORS the last few hours but there is still something central missing in my understanding.

Suppose I'm writing an API that should be usable by clients in their own frontends (that run on a different host of course).

What `access-control-allow-origin` header should your API endpoints actually return?

The wildcard `*` would allow all frontends to actually call my API, but this includes hacker sites, that can now make authenticated requests in the background.

The only way I can imagine is, that I have a whitelist on my server with all allowed client hosts, and if I get a request I check if the host is in that list and then return `access-control-allow-origin: <that-matched-host>`. But this sounds rather cumbersome. And wouldn't really work for really big APIs I guess.

Or is the lesson to learn here that we should not use cookies for authentication?

regards

Comment: *“The only way I can imagine is, that I have a whitelist on my server with all allowed client hosts, and if I get a request I check if the host is in that list and then return `access-control-allow-origin: <that-matched-host>`. But this sounds rather cumbersome.”* As cumbersome as it may sound, that’s exactly what you need to do (well, except that instead of matching the host, you’re matching origin) — at least in the case where the request or response include credentials. That’s how existing CORS libraries do it, and how everybody writing their own custom CORS-handling code does it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#user-credentials), you can not have cookies and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

> The string "*" cannot be used for a resource that supports
>   credentials.

As you wrote, you can either have whitelisted origins or better - avoid using cookies for authentication.
Authentication can be performed by providing some token to the client which will use it in subsequent requests.

In addition, some APIs don't have any user-specific information and there's no authentication. In such cases `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` can fit.